# Access full request info in aiohttp client response

Tags: python, proxy, aiohttp

I would like to logging proxy host and port information for each clinent request in aiohttp. `aiohttp.ClientResponse` class has a `request_info` property which contains very [basic information](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.RequestInfo) about current request.

My current code is:

```py
async with self.session.request(**data) as resp:
    logger.info(
        f'{resp.method} '
        f'{resp.host}:{resp.url.port}'
        f'{resp.url.relative()} '
        f'HTTP/{resp.version.major}.{resp.version.minor} '
        f'{resp.status} '
        f'{resp.content.total_bytes}'
    )
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem a little bit more? Does the example you posted work or cause an error?

Comment: I need to acceess `ClientRequest` object after sending a request. This code shows the place where I need the access to it.